# I cannot turn off cache

Tags: 8, caching

I tried everything to turn the cache off. Even when using drushs command "cr" it does not help.

I used this guide:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

I cannot work like this. I also turned on devels theme rebuild on page view feature. Although I don't understand what is meant with this here:

> Rebuild the theme information like the registry
>   While creating new templates, change the $theme.info.yml and theme_ overrides the theme information needs to be rebuilt.

Example:

```
function theme_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {
    kint("1");
}
```

When changing the number even "drush cr" does not help. I got to refresh like 4 times until the browser shows the change. 
Its not like that with kint - also "var_dump()" needs it's 4,5 times.

Could anybody please tell me what to do?

Comment: There are different types and levels of cache in Drupal 8. Can you edit your question and add which cache cannot be turned off? Or if you're not sure, can you give an example of the behavior you see, what you were expecting/hoping to see instead, and how this tells you that the cache is not properly turned off?

Comment: `drush cr` clears all the caches in drupal. So assuming you did not break drush or the caching system, it could be local browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can be pretty aggressive about caching. Provided you're not using some other caching layers like redis/memcache, varnish, or a CDN, I'd start by disabling the browser cache.

In Firefox, open the inspector and click on the gear icon in the top right to open the Toolbox Options menu. Under the Advanced settings section, check the 'Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)'. I think Chrome is very similar in this.

Also be sure to use the hard refresh option. For Firefox it's Ctrl+f5. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly